# How to address key of retrieved object, in Realm, Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I have created DB for my iOS mobile app using Realm, writing with Swift.
I am trying to find way to look up for matching username and password in DB

This is what I have currently, Attempting filtering and get an object with matching username
I am trying to address attribute/key called password from retrieved object

```
@IBAction func SignInCheck(sender: AnyObject) {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var currentlogin = realm.objects(UserRecords).filter("name = LogUsernameTextField.text") 
//this line causes SIGABRT to be thrown

    if currentlogin.password == LogPasswordTextField.text { //This is the incorrectly addressed line
        ....
    }
}
```

The issue maybe that I am not understanding how objects work in the right way, nor knowing the right syntax to address what I want.

I suspect it is in form of Result but I am still unable to find way to address desired information.

Here is the table structure for your information

```
class UserRecords: Object {
  dynamic var username: String = ""
  dynamic var password: String = ""
  dynamic var latitude: Float = 0
  dynamic var longtitude: Float = 0
}
```

I am open for suggestions better solution and ways of looking up/matching passwords in the table too, if any.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a property called `name` in your `filter` string but in your `UserRecords` class the property is called `username`. Also you have to create the filter string differently:

```
var currentlogin = realm.objects(UserRecords).filter("username = '\(LogUsernameTextField.text!)'")
```

Also be aware that the filter method returns a **list** of `UserRecord` objects that match the filter and not a single object. So calling `if currentlogin.password == ...` will cause an error.

The list only has 1 item (because the username is unique) but it is still a list. So to access the `UserRecord` object you can call `first`:

```
var currentlogin = realm.objects(UserRecords).filter("name = LogUsernameTextField.text!").first
```

Also the `text` property of `UITextField` returns an Optional, so you have to unwrap it.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the main issue I was having, now I am faced with another issue

let currentlogin = realm.objects(UserRecords).filter("username = '\(LogUsernameTextField.text)'").first
        
if currentlogin!.password == LogPasswordTextField.text {

This error was shown: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Is there anything that could be done?

Comment: You forgot the backslash in the filter string. It should be: filter("username = '\(LogUsernameTextField.text)'")

Comment: \ was omitted when I copied over for some reason, my mistake anyway I found my solution

For my case I should have used query as

currentlogin = realm.objects(UserRecords).filter("username == %@", LogUsernameTextField.text!).first

Thanks you so much anyway, would not have been able to solve it without you

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot that `text` returns an Optional so you have to unwrap it. Thanks for the feedback, I added it to the answer.